# One ASP.NET webpage for displaying and editing/ updating information

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have seen that ASP.NET `DetailsView` control can Insert, Display, Edit/ Update information in the same webpage. I would like to do this without using `DetailsView` or any other ADO.NET controls.

How can I display an account information, edit the information and update it (not insertion ) in the same ASP.NET webpage? Can you please describe it in detail?

Comment: Can I please ask why not ADO.NET control? Do you have any experience with ASP.NET MVC (will offerr much cleaner solution)?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some tutorials where this is done with a gridview. There's usually a column marked EDIT, which launches edit mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: I would like to do it manually. I don't want to use any ADO.NET controls.

Comment: That's certainly possible but it's going to be a *lot* of work. You'll basically be taking the classic ASP approach where you need to read data and output an editing interface. Any reason you can't use the built-in .NET databound controls? (You're probably looking at hours vs days or even weeks)

Comment: I will just show one person's information and let the person to edit it. I don't want to use DetailsView or GridView since the row / field need to be selected in order to edit it. It won't meet my requirements.

Comment: Oh, so it's something like a userprofile page? You could just do that with a web form and two panels - one for display, one for edit - that you change based on some action (like clicking an edit button). Then you could just call a function to update your data based on what the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do this yourself.

You can create Labels and TextBoxes on the page, and bind them with public variables in your code behind class.

Then call the `Page.DataBind()` to bind the data.

Sample:

Aspx:

```
Name: <asp:textbox id=txt text="<%# Name %>" runat=server />
Age: <asp:textbox id=txt text="<%# Age %>" runat=server />
```

aspx.cs:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

public int Age { get; set; }

void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Name = "Pascal";
   Age = 1;
   Page.DataBind();
}
```

Refer [Asp.net databinding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860)